# Log Canonical Divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I know the definition of a log canonical divisor and the conditions that a divisor needs to satisfy to be one. But I would like to know why this concept is important. Where is this being applied and what role do these divisors play?

I have just begun reading Miles Reid Undergraduate Geometry and a couple of other basic reading material. So kindly explain in layman terms with some suggestions to additional reading material if possible.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to know about such divisors this early on?

Comment: I started reading a dissertation paper and stumbled upon these divisors. It made me think about their definition and the role they play.